Можно ли в связующей таблице @JoinTable хранить информацию и оперировать с ней?
У меня есть 3 таблицы в postgres: users, dialogs и связующая между ними для отношений many-to-many bi-directional `collocutors.
Entity для таблицы с собеседниками я не создавал и использовал аннотацию @JoinTable для User и Dialog.
Могу ли я, не создавая entity для таблицы collocutors, хранить в ней какие-то значения и оперировать с ними?

Нет, не можете. Если вы будете выполнять  самостоятельные запросы со связной таблицей, то Hibernate будет выкидывать исключения по причине того, что ключи сущностей могут не соответствовать связи ManyToMany. Хотя , вносить изменения в таблицу возможно, но вам надо

не создавая entity

что в свою очередь приводит к ошибке.
Вот пример, как правильно замапить ManyToMany связь.
